# Converting Template to Responsive. Font size, Width in %age, but how about Padding and Margins

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to override Font Size and Page view using

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){
body 
{ 
font-size: 1.2em; 
max-width: 80%;  }
}
```

Where Font Size should increase to 1.2 and width to be reduced by 80%
But the same is not happening due to absolute values in CSS

Is adopting a %age would help in achieving the goal for example

```
.innerpage-bodycontainer-left p { font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

Does replacing Font Size in Em will work on

```
.innerpage-bodycontainer-left p { font: normal .6875em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

For Width

```
.innerpage-bodycontainer-left-text-container .pageing-box{ width:1000px; float: left; }
```

Replacing it in %age

```
.innerpage-bodycontainer-left-text-container .pageing-box{ width:100%; float: left; }
```

But - can i leave Padding and Margins in absolute pixel or is it also required to change them in percentage before adopting media query.

I am a novice in css, has to attempt to convert site to responsive - your advise on % terms for width and Font size in em would assist me in right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **width** in **%age and px**, fonts in **em, %age or px**.

It is up to you to decide wether to change the margin as well or leave them in pixels.

About **%age**:

> Works better if you declare the width of every relative elements.

For example:

```
html,body {
  width:100%;    
  min-width:100%;
}

.mycontainer {
  width:75%; /* will work properly because we have its parent width */
}
<body><div class="mycontainer">...</div></body>
```

About **em**:

> 1em is equal to the current font size. The default text size in browsers is 16px. So, the default size of 1em is 16px.

I'd recommend setting font-size in px in the body tag and only touch paragraphs, links and headings. Example:

```
body {
  font-size:16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size:2em; /* this is equal to 16*2 = 32px */
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em; /* smaller font on mobile. 1.5em == 16+8 == 24px */
   }
}
```

I usually define a standard margin/padding and leave them untouched, while changing the rest of the page with media queries. For example:

```
.mycontainer {
   margin:15px;
   padding:15px;
   font-size:20px;
   width:50%;
   height:200px; /* having a fixed height will help you a lot */
}

/* not specifing margin will leave them untouched */
@media(max-width:992px) {
 .mycontainer {
    font-size:14px;
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
  }
}

/* or you can use em */
@media(max-width:768px) {
  .mycontainer {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    margin:10px; /* here I'm changing the margin for mobile */
    }
}
```